# Loading Angularstrap datepicker CSS from Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

Angularstrap say that it's only dependencies are the bootstrap css styles, but my bootstrap css doesn't include any datepicker styles. What am I missing?

Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: Please delete [Missing bootstrap datepicker styles](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30564600/1407478).  Instead of posting the same question twice (even on the same day) - you should have edited the first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs (http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers ) does talk about some dependency

> Plugin dependency
>
> Datepickers require the [tooltip module](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#tooltips) and
> [dateParser helper](http://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/helpers/date-parser.js) module to be loaded.
>
> These docs currently use [bootstrap-additions](http://github.com/mgcrea/bootstrap-additions/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.less) for styling purposes.

But looking at your screenshot, it seems the icons are not loaded. **Make sure you have [glyphicon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) properly configured in your project. The missing icons are `glyphicon-chevron-left` (left icon) and `glyphicon-chevron-right` (right icon).**

---

These are the additional styles used in the docs (you might need it for styling):

```
.datepicker.dropdown-menu {
    width:250px;
    height:270px;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu button {
    outline:0;
    border:0;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu tbody {
    height:180px;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu tbody button {
    padding:6px;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu.datepicker-mode-1 tbody button, .datepicker.dropdown-menu.datepicker-mode-2 tbody button {
    height:65px;
}
```